# How to use companion factory objects as strategy?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a test which fails intermittently because of ordering issues when I iterate over the values in a `Map`.

Scala helpfully provides a `ListMap` which makes the tests stable, at the expense of performance. So I abstracted the `ImmutableMapFactory` as a val and use it in my code.

```
class C {
  val immutableMapFactory = scala.collection.immutable.Map

  def func = {
    ...
    immutableMapFactory(pairs :_*)
  }
}
```

Now my plan was to extend C and override `immutableMapFactory` for tests

```
class TestableC extends C {
  override val immutableMapFactory = scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
}
```

Unsurprising this fails as `ListMap` does not have the same type as `Map`. How should I specify the  type of the val (or a def) so that I can use the factory wherever I need to create a Map?

Comment: If possible, I suggest making your test resilient to map order.  Or build a `SortedMap` in your test.  Overall, that usually makes things cleaner.

Comment: @dave that's exactly what I'm doing, but I don't want to pay the price of imposing a sort on the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
val immutableMapFactory = scala.collection.immutable.Map
```

This makes `immutableMapFactory` equal to the singleton object `Map`.  `ListMap` (the singleton) is *not* a subclass of `Map` (the singleton), so the subsequent override fails.

If you instead take the `apply` method from `Map`, and partially apply it to form a first class function (of type `(A, B)* => immutable.Map[A,B]`) then the technique can be made to work:

```
import collection.immutable

class Bip {
  def fac[A,B] = immutable.Map.apply[A,B] _
}

class Bop extends Bip {
  override def fac[A,B] = immutable.ListMap.apply[A,B] _
}
```

Comment: I'm reading this as the same as Daniel's option 1, but with more inference?

Comment: With more explanation as to why you had the problem in the first place, and why this works as a fix

Comment: It wasn't a charge of plagiarism, and I prefer your version (for lack of (brackety noise ;-)). I do think it a shame that ImmutableMapFactory can't be used as the type though.

Answer (score 3):

Two possible ways. First, using `def` and functions, which I think is a better abstraction.

```
class C {
  def immutableMapFactory[A,B]: ((A,B)*) => Map[A,B] = scala.collection.immutable.Map.apply _
}

class TestableC extends C {
  override def immutableMapFactory[A,B] = scala.collection.immutable.ListMap.apply _
}
```

Second, using `val`, and structural types:

```
class C {
  val immutableMapFactory: { def apply[A,B](t: (A,B)*): Map[A,B] } = scala.collection.immutable.Map
}

class TestableC extends C {
  override val immutableMapFactory: { def apply[A,B](t: (A,B)*): Map[A,B] } = scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of specifying the type of the function rather than that of the value.

Comment: Although as I look at it, this solves the problem only for one operation. What if there were more? Isn't the point of `object` rather than `static` that I can still swap behaviour given a common interface? Is there really no way to express the common supertype of the ListMap and Map companion objects?

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor Yes and no. To swap this behavior requires that the object implements an interface. As it happens, there's one such trait -- `scala.collection.generic.ImmutableMapFactory` -- which, unfortunately, is not co-variant, so you can't replace `IMF[ListMap]` for `IMF[Map]`. I'll open a ticket about it, but there might well be variance issues preventing it.

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor Actually, I just tried, and `ImmutableMapFactor` cannot be co-variant. It breaks the definition of `CanBuildFrom`. Maybe there's a way around it, but, even if it is possibly, I doubt it would be easy.

Comment: Thanks, I had been trying to specify the type as `ImmutableMapFactory`, but failing.